# ionRangeSlider - как обратиться к объекту с параметрами?

Tags: javascript, rangeslider, ion-rangeslider

Пытаюсь модифицировать слайдер: на странице их пять штук. Задача - чтобы можно было кликнуть в значение над ползунком и задать ручками цифры.

Для передачи указанного значения в слайдер есть функция:

```
instance.update({from: val});
```

Для отрисовки слайдеров создаю их по 5 раз, в итоге получаю, что есть 5 *range*, 5 *instance*, т.е.:

```
instance0 = $range0.data("ionRangeSlider");
 ................ 
instance4= $range4.data("ionRangeSlider");
```

Я знаю текущий номер *instance*, который мне и нужно проапдейтить, он у меня хранится в переменной `activeSlider`.

Как сделать обновление нужного слайдера?

Пытаюсь что-то типа:

```
(instance + activeSlider).update({from: val});
```

но, конечно, это не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сохраняйте инстансы не в переменные, а в ячейки массива
2. Обращайтесь к ним по номеру

Пример кода:

```
var instances = [];
instances[0] = $range0.data("ionRangeSlider");
instances[1] = $range1.data("ionRangeSlider");

// далее

instances[activeSlider].update({from: val}); // обновить нужный
```

Comment: Денис, вы и тут)))) Точно, вот я нуб(((( Спасибо!